# How to sudo a bash script whose parent dir is in the $PATH?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, sudo

For example

`~/Desktop/scripts` is in `$PATH`

`cat ~/Desktop/scripts/hi`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo hi
```

What I have tried(The current dir is ~):

```
hi # CLI said "hi"
sudo -E hi # sudo: hi: command not found
se hi # sudo: hi: command not found # alias se="sudo -E "
```

How to sudo the script?

Comment: Fix the she-bang first, it should be `#!/bin/bash` with no spaces

Comment: Can you try it as `sudo -E bash ~/hi`

Comment: @Inian I have fixed the she-bang and `sudo -E bash ~/hi` reported `No such file or directory`

Comment: `~/hi` is not the script location, so the `No such file or directory` error is normal. I guess @Inian meant `sudo -E bash ~/Desktop/scripts/hi`.

Comment: @n00dl3 I agree with you. I just want to use the command $PATH to avoid completing the script's path.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91541/why-is-path-reset-in-a-sudo-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sudo PATH="${PATH}" bash -c "hi"
```

For the explanation please see man sudoers(5):

> By default, the env_reset option is enabled.  This causes commands to be executed with a new, minimal environment.  On AIX (and Linux systems without PAM), the environment is initialized with the contents of the /etc/environment file.  The new environment contains the TERM, PATH, HOME, MAIL, SHELL, LOGNAME, USER, USERNAME and SUDO_* variables in addition to variables from the invoking process permitted by the env_check and env_keep options.  This is effectively a whitelist for environment variables.

Comment: Change ~/Desktop/scripts to a full path, i.e. /home/user/Desktop/scripts

Comment: Your `PATH` point is right. `sudo PATH="${PATH}" bash hi` works!

Comment: `bach` should be `bash`